# PCA for questionnaire reduction

Tags: pca, feature-selection, stata, factor-analysis, survey

I'd like to have some opinion regarding if I'm in the right way with my questionnaire reduction. I have a questionnaire with 275 questions and 34 issues (so a couple of questions are related to each issue) and about 700 respondents. All the answers were transformed in dummies (1 or 0).

In order to know which question is more relevant to build the issues in according to the response pattern, I'm applying PCA method with Stata. Here are the steps I'm following (separately for each "issue"):

1. Checking the quality of the data (in some cases we have very few answers comparing to the group, so I'm dropping these ones out the analysis)
2. Performing a KMO test (factortest), in order to check if the data are suitable to PCA (just using the ones that have KMO > 0.5)
3. Performing a tetrachoric matrix (because I have dichotomous variables)
4. Using matrix = r(Rho) in order to get the PCA from this matrix and not the Pearson's one.
5. Decide the number of components I should retain.

And then, in order to decide which question I'm gonna take out of the questionnaire, I'm checking the loadings of the components I kept. The lower is the loading, the most likely this question will be excluded.

In general I'm using just the component which explains better all the issue (i.g Financial Planning).

Does it make sense? Am I in the right way?

Comment: I think PCA isn't really the best idea when you have only binary variables. Factor analysis is a possibility (see this question and answers: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/180733/reduction-of-questionnaire-via-fa-versus-control-group?rq=1). Also, welcome to the site!

Comment: @amoeba, I'm doing it separately, for exemple: I have a issue called Financial Planning, and this issue has 7 questions. I aplied PCA to check which question was more more important to build the issue. And also all of them are measuring the same thing: financial planning.

Comment: @Firebug thanks for the link! I've checked it before but I thought I could go on with PCA. I'll read again and maybe have other understanding. As you can realise, by background is not in statistics so I'm very confuse about how to conduct it.

Comment: @JulianaJacobowiski neither is mine, I have a BSc in medical physics, the most important part is the will to learn. It seems like there's some comprehensive material written about the procedure for stata, like this one: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/faq/efa_categorical.htm (great site btw).

Comment: What's your rationale for removing the items with a low loading? I've not given this a huge amount of thought, and I'm not familiar with your items or the measurement model you're trying to construct, but could you not have an item that doesn't load well (because it's weakly correlated with the other items) but is still a theoretically important item? I'm not saying you're doing the wrong thing, but if I was trying to eliminate items I'd be hesitant about doing it solely on the basis of numbers and not on the content of the item, so I'm interested in your standpoint on this issue

Comment: @Ian_Fin, in some occasions I'll not be able to remove the items, because they can measure something that it's a law statement and it must be asked (or because it's something very important and must be asked even if it does not help me to describe the principal characteristcs of the data).

Comment: @Ian_Fin However, as the questions have the same underlying structure (they are measuring separetely things like planting quality, cost control and so on), I believe if I remove the low loading I'll keep the principal characteristics of the data without losing information and at the same time reaching my aim, that is reduce the number of the questions. Reading about PCA applyed for questionnaires it's basically how they do in order to reduce questions. My principal concerns are related to the kind of data I'm working with: just binaries.

Comment: @Firebug This page was one I was following in order to perform PCA; I just change the imput to be a PCa instead of FA. They are quite similar, but all data reduction in questionnaires I read use PCA instead of FA. Thanks again! (The thing about tetrachoric matrix I got from there too; as mine are just dichotomous variabels, they said that tetrachoric would be better than the polychoric).

Comment: @JulianaJacobowiski as long as you're always using tetra/polychoric correlations then what you're proposing sounds reasonable. I suppose one question I might have though is why are you doing step 5 when it sounds like you know in advance how many components there should be (you mentioned planting quality, cost control, etc.)

Comment: @Ian_Fin, I know the components, exactly, but I have 35 issues that sums 275 questions. Some of them I have 15 questions, other ones 7... So I'm applying PCA in order to find out which questions (or variables) are more important to build each issue (or component as you said). Then I can remove the ones that have a low loading and try to avoid that the respondent spend about 3 hours answering it without losing the information quality. But I really don't know if it makes sense. My teacher (who is PhD in Economy) told me to do that, but in fact he doesn't have a big background in PCA.

Comment: @JulianaJacobowiski Has the data from your questionnaire been subjected to a factor analysis to confirm that the questions map onto the issues in the way you expect? That would probably be my first step before thinking about producing a short form

Comment: @JulianaJacobowiski You may be interested to read [this paper](http://journal.sjdm.org/8323/jdm8323.pdf) which uses internal (including loadings, but this time from CFA) and external criteria to produce a short form of an existing questionnaire

Comment: @Ian_Fin You mean all the data or the data separeted by issue? I didn't do that, but I'll check how to apply and interpretate. Thank you! And also thank you for the paper, I'll have a look!

Comment: @JulianaJacobowiski All of the data. If you do an EFA with 34 factors then you'd hopefully find that the questions all load (to some degree) onto the appropriate issues.